# Heroku got an error No such app in .herokuapp domain

Tags: node.js, heroku

I saw another who has the same issue. But they got this issue when using their own domain name. I use the .herokuapp.com domain name but got this issue. There's no error in the console.
And when I refresh the request many many times it sends to me a response and after that, it will be a No such app again.

```
2021-11-24T06:56:36.965623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=paiya-server.herokuapp.com request_id=f4f29684-0ce3-4bf6-ae3e-9aff47417a7d fwd="27.55.65.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=241 protocol=https
```

This is the console when I send a request and get a No such app error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've solved it. I change my domain name in Heroku from paiya-server to paiyaserver. I removed (-) and now it's can work perfectly.